# Kubernetes - HPA won't autoscale the pods

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I am deploying my microservice application I built using node.

## Issue

The pods won't autoscale when I put load using **Jmeter**. The CPU utitilization goes to **50m**, which doesn't invoke HPA to start autoscaling. I want it to start replicating as soon as it reaches 80% of the CPU request(which is 10m).

> **HPA config :**

```yaml
# apiVersion: autoscaling/v1 
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler 
metadata: 
  name: client-hpa 
  namespace: default 
spec: 
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 4  
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 80
  scaleTargetRef: 
    # apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment 
    name: client-depl
```

> **Deployment config :**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
    name: client-depl 
spec: 
    replicas: 1
    selector: 
        matchLabels: 
            app: client 
    template: 
        metadata:
            labels: 
                app: client 
        spec: 
            containers: 
                - name: client 
                  image: <docker-id>/<image-name>
                  resources: 
                    requests: 
                        memory: 350Mi
                        cpu: 10m    ### I want it to autoscale when it reaches 8m ###
```

Also, `kubectl get hpa` shows the following output :

```
$ kubectl get hpa
NAME         REFERENCE                TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
client-hpa   Deployment/client-depl   <unknown>/80%   1         4         1          8m32s
```

Comment: Do you have metrics-server installed?

Comment: Good question from @AliTou, because the older versions did not have metrics-server installed. At least on AKS.

Answer (score 0):

HPA is based on the following equtation

[desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details)

As you can notice, equation is based on current cpu utilization and not on CPU requests. (I want it to autoscale when it reaches 8m).

That said, perhaps the following maybe of interest to you:

[Vertical Pod Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler)

Comment: So the percentage I specified will be in reference to the models CPU? I'm not sure that's the case, because I've seen docs using 80%. It won't make sense if it's based on Node's CPU. Can you elaborate? *I want horizontal pod scaling*

Comment: The percentage you specified is the desired average cpu across all pods of your deployment. You are right that is not Node CPU. You also need to make distinction between cpu request and current cpu value, they are different.

Comment: Let me give an example, if current cpu value is 63% and desired is 80%, and current replicas is 3, we have (63/80)*3=2.36, so desired is 3.

Comment: What is 80% here? And 80% of what?

Comment: 80% average pod cpu across deployment

Comment: So in your case equation is (A/80)*1=desired replicas, where A is the actual cpu usage. So any value just above 80, should bring desired replicas to scale up to 2.

Comment: How i came up with the above, from your kubectl get hpa, we know that desired metric value =80, current replica =1.

Comment: How will I calculate A? Also, when you say ```where A is the actual cpu usage``` for my current deployment ?

Comment: A can be seen from "kubectl get hpa", right now its unknown in your 1st post. It can also be seen on UI, Kubernetes>workload>deployment>details>HPA